How to create drop down searchable component with auto select in Angular?
I am creating an input field which is autocompleting the remaining part of text inside the input field and also showing suggestions below the input field in select options. Now I want that while typing in input field I should see the relevant option as highlighted.
I tried putting value in mat-select but it is not working, please guide how to create a component like given below for reference.
thank you


Show some code please

You can use Angular Material's mat-autocomplete component. To achieve this.
Refer the code below:
app.compoennt.html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <label>Enter text</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    matInput
    [formControl]="myControl"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  />
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

app.component.ts :
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter((option) =>
      option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    );
  }
}

app.module.ts:
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}


Refer the working stackblitz here


Ok, but it doesn't automatically select first relevant match...

Modify the filter value method to set selects value from controller itself via two data binding

@SelakaNanayakkara Thank you for the answer but I'm able to create something like this, but my main issue is while typing I don't want it to filter the options but i want the most matching one to be auto-selected and the text to be populated in blue with the most matching one menu option, it;s a bit complicated but any help would be appreciated, please guide me for any suggestions. Please check the screenshot i have added in my question.
